# How can I combine these two similar methods into one?

Tags: c#

The methods below are just inverses of one another.  I suspect that I can combine the logic into one method.  I prefer to avoid Reflection.  Is it possible to combine them and maintain readability?

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabEntity selectedItem = bindingSource1.Current as LabEntity;
        selectedLabsData.Add(selectedItem);
        availableLabsData.Remove(selectedItem);
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabEntity selectedItem = bindingSource2.Current as LabEntity;//new binding source
        availableLabsData.Add(selectedItem);//called Add instead of remove
        selectedLabsData.Remove(selectedItem);//called Remove instead of Add
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how you can do more than that. Operating on different items and doing different things with them. Abstracting further than this would reduce readability and understandability of your code.

Comment: Combining both methods as one will complicate more. I think current implementation looks readable.

Comment: don't overengineer it -- this is pretty simple to read and maintain

Comment: I agree with @FirozAnsari, but one change I would make is to have the second line in both methods act on selectedLabsData, and the third line avalableLabsData so it's more clear that one adds/removes, and the other removes/adds.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could factor out the logic into a helper method:

```
private void ListFixup(object entity, List<Item> addList, List<Item> removeList)
{
    LabEntity selectedItem = entity as LabEntity;
    // don't forget your error checking here

    addList.Add(selectedItem);
    removeList.Remove(selectedItem);
}

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListFixup(bindingSource1.Current, selectedLabsData, availableLabsData);
}

private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListFixup(bindingSource2.Current, availableLabsData, selectedLabsData);
}
```

I'm not sure this helps readability, but it does reduce code duplication.

Comment: First correct answer... And I agree that this isn't helping readability.

Comment: I need to add some null checking logic too.  So I wanted to see if there was some way to combine it all in a readable way.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SwapThem( bindingSource1, selectedLabsData, availableLabsData );
}

private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SwapThem( bindingSource2, availableLabsData, selectedLabsData );
}

// I just don't know the proper type-cast of the "toAddTo" and "toRemoveFrom" parameters.
private void SwapThem( BindingSource bs, List<yourType> toAddTo, List<yourType> toRemoveFrom )
{
   LabEntity selectedItem = bs.Current as LabEntity;
   toAddTo.Add(selectedItem);
   toRemoveFrom.Remove(selectedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to refactor the two methods that wouldn't result in significantly reducing the readability of the code, you can see this in some of the other answers posted. This is a case where the level of code duplication is acceptable for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tag to the sender?

```
private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Button *myButton = (Button)sender;
if (myButton.tag == 1){
        LabEntity selectedItem = bindingSource1.Current as LabEntity;
        selectedLabsData.Add(selectedItem);
        availableLabsData.Remove(selectedItem);
}
else {
LabEntity selectedItem = bindingSource2.Current as LabEntity;//new binding source
        availableLabsData.Add(selectedItem);//called Add instead of remove
        selectedLabsData.Remove(selectedItem);//called Remove instead of Add
}
}
```

I havn't checked this for compiler errors, It is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

Have both buttons link to a single event handler. The handler could then look something like this: (excuse the multiple checks on the buttons as I don't know what type to declare holders for 'availableLabsData' and 'selectedLabsData' as):

```
    private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var bindingSource = (sender == btnRemove) ? bindingSource2 : bindingSource1;   
        var selectedItem = source.Current as LabEntity;
        if(sender == btnRemove) 
        {
            availableLabsData.Add(selectedItem);
            selectedLabsData.Remove(selectedItem);
        }
        else if(sender == btnAdd)
        {
            availableLabsData.Remove(selectedItem);
            selectedLabsData.Add(selectedItem);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone's right about not going overboard at the expense of making the code less readable

The only thought I have is ...

From just the code posted but it looks like `selectedLabsData` and `availableLabsData` are tightly intertwined so I wouldn't put logic related to them in your event handlers.  Put the logic in different methods (preferably a different class) so that you don't ever accidentally update one without updating the other.  This has the benefit of making the methods in question simpler and more "readable".

```
private void LabsDataAdded(LabEntity value)
{
    selectedLabsData.Add(value);
    availableLabsData.Remove(value);
}

private void LabsDataRemoved(LabEntity value)
{
    availableLabsData.Add(value);
    selectedLabsData.Remove(value);
}
```

then the methods would just be:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabsDataAdded(bindingSource1.Current as LabEntity);
}

private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabsDataRemoved(bindingSource2.Current as LabEntity);
}
```

Even better, you could use lambda expressions to make the code even more succinct:

```
btnAdd.Clicked += (sender, e) => LabsDataAdded(bindingSource1.Current as LabEntity);
btnAdd.Clicked += (sender, e) => LabsDataRemoved(bindingSource1.Current as LabEntity);
```

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabEntity selectedItem = bindingSource1.Current as LabEntity;
    RemoveItemFromList(selectedItem);
}

private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LabEntity selectedItem = bindingSource2.Current as LabEntity;//new binding source
    RemoveItemFromList(selectedItem);
}

private void RemoveItemFromList(LabEntity ent)
{
    selectedLabsData.Add(ent);
    availableLabsData.Remove(ent);
}
```

Comment: Nope. The OP is adding and removing from _different_ lists.

Comment: In you`r example there are two different sources and you create same operation on the same two lists?

Comment: The OP _isn't_ performing the _same_ operation. Read the two methods _carefully_. `selectedLabsData.Add != availableLabsData.Add`